# Translate Data from Multiple Dataframe Columns to Create A Sentence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create sentences summarizing multiple countries stats using a World Bank file. I would like to use the data in the dataframe to create the sentences.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['United States','Canada','Mexico'],'GDP':[2.9, 1.9, 2.0],'CPI':[2.4, 2.3, 4.9]}

def risky(val):
    if val < 2.2:
        return "at a high risk"
    else:
        return "not at a high risk"

for i in df.columns.values().tolist():
    df[i] = df[i].apply(risky)

def text_app(country, ind):
    line1 = df["country"].map(str) + " is " df["GDP"].map(str) + " of 
    defaulting."`
```

I keep receiving the following error:

```
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "method") to str"
```

Output from df[i].apply(risky) is as expected:

```
country|    GDP|  CPI
United States|  not at a high risk| not at a high risk
Canada| at a high risk| not at a high risk
Mexico| at a high risk| not at a high risk
```

Expected Output is:

```
"Canada is at a high risk of defaulting."
"United States is not at a high risk of defaulting."
"Mexico is at a high risk of defaulting."
```

Comment: Let us know the expected output please

Comment: In the last function, you're trying to concatenate a series to strings. You'd need to extract the specific strings to concatenate to the static strings you're using.  Edit: Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: @cs95 I added more context with the output of the first def and the expected output of the second def.

Comment: @krewsayder Thank you for the warm welcome. Are you referring to something like the following:
line1 = df["country"] + " is " df["country"]["ind"] + " of defaulting."

text_app("Canada", "GDP")
>>> Canada is at a high risk of defaulting.

Comment: You could do something like this, I believe.  df['out'] = df["country"].map(str) + " is " df["GDP"].map(str) + " of 
    defaulting."`  EDIT: Or else you need to loop through the dataframe.